# conceptual framework

Tags: education-research

The undergraduate students are having difficulty in solving problems like algebra and geometry in a classroom. In order to improve their poor performance in mathematics, an intervention (enhancement program) is to be introduced. At first i have to assess their mathematical performance by giving them a pretest. After analyzing the pretest, an enhancement program is introduced by teaching them selected topics in Algebra and Geometry using cooperative learning, peer tutoring, mastery, feedback and reward system. Afterwards, a post-test will be given to see if the enhancement program is effective or not. There will be also an interview to students to know their perception about the enhancement program.
What is the best conceptual framework for this study?

Comment: How does a conceptual framework differ from a paradigm conceptual framework, and what criteria do you use in comparing them?

Comment: I should have asked the conceptual framework instead of paradigm conceptual framework. I like to make a conceptual framework for my study. My study is about the poor mathematical performance of the students. I like to introduce an enhancement program to my students. what will be the best conceptual framework?

Answer (score 5):

A conceptual framework should inform the experimental design, not be something that you add on like a garnish after the entire experiment has been planned.  You say that the students are having trouble with "problems like algebra and geometry".  What *specifically* are they having trouble with?  What do you think is the reason why they are having those problems?  Why do you think the proposed intervention would be useful?  You seem to have planned the entire intervention without giving thought to those questions.  Answer those question *first*.  That's your conceptual framework.  Then use the answers to design the intervention.